# Keycloak instance Service type as Node Port using Keycloak kubernetes operator

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, on-premises-instances, keycloak-operator

I have Deployed keycloak operator on Kubernetes (on-premises) then I deployed a kind as keycloak as one instance pods up and running service was exposing as Cluster IP but I want change that as NodePort here is my manifest file.

```
apiVersion: k8s.keycloak.org/v2alpha1
kind: Keycloak
metadata:
  name: example-keycloak
spec:
  unsupported:
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: keycloak
            args:
              - start-dev
```

```
here, I tried at the under the spec section type: NodePort 

and 

service:

   type: NodePort 

But, There is no luck, can you guys help me to overcome that problem

Thanks.
```

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).